# How can i specify that a particular flyway migration script be run on a different database

Tags: sql, database, scripting, flyway

I have some migration scripts in my db.migration folder that run on my default database server. I want to add a new migration script but i want it to be run on an entirely different server, without affecting the previous migration scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially need two separate configurations:

- put migration scripts for server A in a folder and specify that folder as a location in `A.conf`, which also has the JDBC connection url for server A
- do the same for server B in a separate folder and specify it in `B.conf`
- then `flyway migrate -configFiles=A.conf`.

This is fine even if you want the migration version numbers to run in one contiguous sequence.